# Google Chrome displays css style correctly only after a refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm currently coding a script in javascript in order to display images into a web page. These images are loaded with an ajax request and a css style is directly applied from jquery. The script works with firefox/Opera/IE, but Google Chrome doesn't display correctly the CSS.

When I debug the HTML page with Google Chrome, the code is correct and the images contain the right css style. If I uncheck and check an attribute in the css editor panel, chrome refreshes the style and displays correctly all the elements.

The code is visible below

```
function displayCroppedFace(faceData, parentElem) {
    var randomid = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 32));
    $("#" + parentElem).append("<div id=\"faceImg_border_" + randomid + "\" />");
    $("#faceImg_border_" + randomid).append("<div id=\"faceImg" + randomid + "\" />");
    $("#faceImg" + randomid).attr('class','cropped_model');
    $('#faceImg' + randomid).append('<img id="faceImg' + randomid + '_img" src="' + faceData.image_url + '"/>');
    $('#faceImg' + randomid + '_img').load(function() {
        crop($(this), faceData.x, faceData.y, faceData.w, faceData.h);
    });
}

function crop(imgObj, x, y, width, height) {
    var originalWidth = imgObj.width();
    var originalHeight = imgObj.height();
    var scale_x = imgObj.parent().width() / (width + 20);
    var scale_y = imgObj.parent().height() / (height + 20);


    imgObj.css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'display' : 'block',
        'left' : (-x * scale_x - 5) + 'px',
        'top' : (-y * scale_y - 5) + 'px',
        'width' : (originalWidth * scale_x + 10) + 'px',
        'height' : (originalHeight * scale_y + 10) + 'px',
        'z-index' : '10'
    });
}
```

`faceData` is a javascript object that contains an image url and four coordinates (x, y, w, h).

Is anybody know what is the problem with Google Chrome and how to do in order to fix this error?

Comment: Inside your crop function, can you do a `console.log(width, height)` and see if it is zero?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The error was in the CSS.